# UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE even if permissions are correct

Tags: git, ssh

UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE even if permissions are correct. I tried with both 600 and 400

Following is from Console.

Surprisingly it works from cygwin. Same path for keys. Only difference I see is ssh agent ?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.112]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\source\git\project>git pull
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\<user>/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\<user>/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
git@bitbucket.organisation.no: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\source\git\project>ls -alh C:\\Users\\<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
-r--r--r-- 1 <user> Domain Users 3.4K Jan 13 12:48 'C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa'

C:\source\git\project>ssh -vvvT git@bitbucket.organisation.no
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.4
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:\\ProgramData\\ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.organisation.no" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.organisation.no[xxx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
```

From Cygwin

```
$ ssh -vvvT git@bitbucket.organisation.no
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.organisation.no" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.organisation.no [xxx.xx.xxx.xx] port 22.
```

UPDATE : Something is strange in way I am checking permissions ?

```
C:\Users\user\.ssh>ls -alh id_rsa
-r--------+ 1 user Domain Users 3.4K Jan 13 12:48 id_rsa

C:\Users\user\.ssh>ls -alh C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa
-r--r--r-- 1 user Domain Users 3.4K Jan 13 12:48 'C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa'
```

Comment: `-r--r--r--` is certainly too open. Also check the permissions on the very directory `.ssh/`.

Comment: How does Windows 10 and its various overlays translate between whatever Windows 10's native access rights are (apparently there is no such thing as "group" here), and Unix-style "group" and "other" permissions?

Comment: @torek: Windows stores it as metadata on each file. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that your private key file is not readable by other users than yourself. Right now, it is readable to everyone.

To fix the permissions on your private key file, you can thus run something like:

```
chmod o-rwx C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: Well it seems permissions are correct ? can you see update I made to post. I am using Windows Cmd

Answer (score 0):

You should change the owner of the file(which contains the private key)to your username with full access. and then remove the other usernames that have access to that file.

1. Right Click on the file which contains the private key and clicks on properties and then Security tab> Advanced by clicking on the change button you can change the owner to your username. (if you don't know the name of your username run: "echo %USERNAME%" in the command prompt.) Change>Advanced...>Find Now
2. Remove all Permission entries except the one you just added.

click on Disable inheritance> Convert inherited permissions... then remove all Permission entries except the one you just added.